# checking 'deepest' element in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a `map<int, map<int, int>>`.

The first key stands for node, the second key stands for an attribute, and the 'deepest' element represents a particular value.

I need to check that element, but doing the following unnecessary adds keys to my map:

```
map<int, map<int, int>> test;
if (test[4][3] > 5)
{
    //do something
}
```

The alternative as I think of it is

```
map<int, map<int, int>> test;
if (test.find(4) != test.end())
{
    if (test[4].find(3) != test[4].end())
    {
        if (test[4][3] > 5)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I don't know if there exists the key `[4][3]` in the map, and I don't want to unnecessarily add it. Thanks!

Comment: mistake in typing on my part - edited now

Comment: *"Is there a better way to do this?"* - At least don't use `find(4)` and then `test[4]` immediately aftwerwards, since that will search the value *twice*, in your case *four times* (what do you think `find` returns?). Always keep in mind that a `[]` access on a map doesn't come as free as it does with an array or vector, it's O(log n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work - first you search in the first map and saves the returned iterator, then if that iterator is valid you search the map that he points to and saves the result in another iterator, and if he's valid that means that the objects you seek exists and you just check the value of it:

```
map<int, map<int, int>> test;
map<int, map<int, int>>::iterator it1;
map<int, int>::iterator it2;
if ((it1 = test.find(4)) != test.end())
{
    if ((it2 = it1->second.find(3)) != it1->second.end())
    {
        if (it2->second > 5)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: thanks for this - but how does it differ from my second implementation?

Comment: Might be clearer if you declared & initialized the iterators in one step then checked against end() in another.

Comment: @sccs: yours has to do twice the searches. Once in the find()s and again in the indexing []s. This one saves the result of each find, and operates on that directly.

Comment: Your second implementation has few problems: 1. When doing this: `test.find(3)` you search in the node map and not the attributes map.
2. Yours is doing 2 extra (unnecessary) searches in the last step while mine is directly assessing the value using the iterator

Comment: @TomerArazy I've corrected that from (`test.find(3)` to `test[4].find(3)` now - it was a mistake!

Comment: Every time you do [] on a map, it's just as complex as find(). Find returns an iterator, which is like a pointer to the node it found. Tomer's version uses that in the inner parts instead of having to search for it every time.

Comment: @sccs - Although doing test[4] looks likes direct access, it isn't! it's actually performing a search in the tree (log(n)), you need to save the result someplace else to avoid that (edit: or what Matthew said ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Not fundamentally different from Tomer Arazy's suggestion, but making use of C++11's `decltype` to get rid of repeated type declarations (correcting which can be tedious when you modify the data type of the map):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  using std::map;

  map<int, map<int, int>> test;
  test[4][3] = 6;

  decltype(test.begin())                 outer;
  decltype(test.begin()->second.begin()) inner;

  if (((outer = test.find(4)) != test.end())
      && ((inner = outer->second.find(3)) != outer->second.end())
      && (inner->second > 5))
    std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

(Note that the argument of `decltype()` isn't evaluated, so this works even if the map is empty.)

This will obviously only work with C++11.

---

Another thing to mention in the context of C++11 is that `std::map` has now an `at()` function similar to `std::vector`. It returns the value for a given key, and throws an exception if the key doesn't exist. This only a useful idea if you consider the non-existence of the key as an error condition. But if so, you could use

```
if (test.at(4).at(3) > 5)
  std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;
```

And then possibly catch the `std::out_of_range` exception somewhere.

Comment: It's nice - another way with C++11 would be to use `auto`

Comment: @TomerArazy Just that you couldn't put the assignments into the if and thus use a single if for the whole thing, would be similar to *Mathew*'s code just with proper `auto`s. Depends on what one values more ugly, nested ifs for what could be a mere conjunction of predicates, or non-initializing variable declarations with ugly `decltype`s.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might make it a bit easier to see what's going on:

```
map<int, map<int, int>> test; 
map<int, map<int, int>>::iterator outer = test.find(4);
if (outer != test.end())
{
    map<int, int>::iterator inner = outer->second.find(3);
    if (inner != outer->second.end())
    {
        if (inner->second > 5)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```